# Uncheck button when buttons are exclusive in Qt Quick Controls 2

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I need to make list of checkable `AbstractButton`'s that should be exclusive ,but by default I cannot uncheck checked button with no one button checked.

Now I have to make something like this to imitate such logic:

```
Item {
    AbstractButton {
        id: oneButton
        checkable: true
        onCheckedChanged: {
            if(checked) {
                if(twoButton.checked || threeButton.checked || ...) {
                    twoButton.checked = threeButton.checked = ... = false
                }
            }
        }
    }

    AbstractButton {
        id: twoButton
        checkable: true
        onCheckedChanged: {
            if(checked) {
                if(oneButton.checked || threeButton.checked || ...) {
                    oneButton.checked = threeButton.checked = ... = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

This is ugly and it would be great to find better solution.

Comment: Just curious, what's the intended usage for this? That is, what would the UI look like?

Comment: @Mitch are there any exclusive group GUI elements that allow "no choice"?

Comment: @dtech I think you can start off with no button selected, but once one is selected there always has to be one selected.

Comment: So there is some use niche. Although I guess you can just as easily have a "no choice" button, although that will use extra screen space.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I was asking about what the UI would look like - I was thinking that a ComboBox with a "None" or "Please select an option" item could be an alternative.

Comment: @Mitch, well, actually it is useful in vertical toolbar, where group of controls can be folded/unfolded by clicking on group title. Due to restriction on available height it is useful to keep only one group unfolded or unfold all groups to save space. I hope I've succeed in explaining it clearly enough.

Answer (score 5):

You can have an uncheckable exclusive button by forcing it to uncheck on release :

```
Button {
    checkable: true
    autoExclusive: true
    property bool wasChecked
    onPressed: wasChecked = checked
    onReleased: {
        if (wasChecked) {
            checked = false;
            toggled(); // emit the toggled signal manually, since we changed the checked value programmatically but it still originated as an user interaction.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if user uncheck it by keyboard? I thing it will not work.

Comment: Indeed you also need to handle `Key.onPressed` and `onReleased` for space.

Comment: My code includes `checked: model.checked`, I think it will be more suitable.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
Column {
  id: col
  spacing: 2
  property int choice: -1
  Repeater {
    model: 5
    delegate: Button {
      checkable: true
      checked: col.choice === index
      onClicked: col.choice = (col.choice === index ? -1 : index)
      text: "Button " + index
    }
  }
  Text {
    text:  "Choice is " + (col.choice > -1 ? col.choice : "undefined")
  }
}
```

Note that the GUI will update property even if `choice` is set from somewhere else, or if you have that button group in more than one place in the GUI, as long as they all share the same `choice`.

Comment: Buttons can't be created by `Repeater` since each of them has it own `contentItem` and some different attached properties.

Comment: @KamilZaripov the repeater is just for the sake of getting a short working example code. You don't have to use a repeater in your code. And instead of using the index int you can manually specify to use whatever you want.